# How to query across 2 entity kinds with matching properties? [Google Cloud Datastore]

Tags: python, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I mostly use SQL. noSQL is a bit new for me, so please bear with me.

Let's say I have 2 entities in the google cloud datastore

```
The first entity:
User Entity, who's key is an email id
which has the properties
-email: a string containing an email
-user_name: a string containing the user name

The second entity: 
Task Entity, who's key is an int id
which has the properties
-owner_email: a string containing an owner's email 
-details: a string detailing the Task
-deadline: a datetime deadline
```

Now let's say I want to fetch the owner_email and details from task entities and the name from the user entities. Further more, I only want entites where the deadline = <ceratin date>.

In SQL this would be easy.

```
SELECT A.OWNER_EMAIL, A.DETAILS, B.NAME 
FROM TASK A, USERS B 
WHERE A.DEADLINE = '2012-12-20' 
AND A.OWNER_EMAIL = B.EMAIL;
```

Unfortunately the gcloud_datastore is not SQL. How would I got about performing this task in NoSQL.

I've considered some options. One was denormalising and creating a user_name property in tasks. But this is a bit hacky and it'll be a pain to change usernames. I've tried ancestor keys. But that won't work as I have multiple entities linked this way. And finally I've considered a for loop on the back end which goes round and fetched the user name. But that is a hodge-podge of a solution, and quite expensive. For what it's worth, here is my current code.

```
owner = user_info.get('email')
deadln = eu.get_latest_deadln()
query = datastore_client.query(kind='Task')
query.add_filter(eu.TASK.DEADLINE, '=', deadln)
results = list(query.fetch())
#TODO - get the user name associated with each task
return results
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this is noSQL (which assumes you have denormalized your data and everything is self contained which in turn means no primary and foreign keys), you would have to run 2 queries -

- one to get the user data
- and then another query to get the task for each corresponding email in the returned user data.

The above 2 queries would normally run in series but using the [ndb library](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/index.html) and [tasklets](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/tasklets.html?highlight=tasklet), you can run them **concurrently** which makes it much faster

Sample code could be something like

```
@ndb.tasklet
def getTaskDetails(userDetail):
    # userDetail is a complete row of data from the User table (kind/model)
    q_1 = Tasks.query(Tasks.owner_email == userDetail.email)
    tasks = yield q_1.fetch_async()
    raise ndb.Return ((userDetail, tasks))

    # To return only the email, try  
    # raise ndb.Return ((userDetail.email, tasks))


# First create the query to get user data
q = Users.query()

# Instead of fetching the results, you pass it (via map function) 
# to a tasklet which will return the task details
results = q.map(getTaskDetails)

# results will be a tuple of (userDetail, tasks)
```

If your User Entity had a lot of fields and you only needed one field in your final query, it would make sense to modify your Task model to

```
class Task(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="User", required=True)
    # We've replaced owner email with the Id (Key) of a specific row
    # in the user table (model)

    details = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    deadline = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required = True)
```

With the above modification, you can change your query to

```
@ndb.tasklet
def getTaskDetails(user):
    # user variable is the key of a specific user record
    q_1 = Tasks.query(Tasks.user == user)
    tasks = yield q_1.fetch_async()
    # We're going to return just the email and then tasks
    raise ndb.Return ((user.get().email, tasks))


q = Users.query(keys_only = True) 
# The above says to return just the record key. This is
# a faster query to run

results = q.map(getTaskDetails)
```

Comment: Hmm, isn't ndb outdated?

Comment: No, it isn't. My answer linked to the library (the Cloud Version). Maybe you're thinking of the bundled API for NDB and if so, that isn't outdated either because Google updated it to provide support for Python 3 (see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access))

Comment: Ok, but is there an answer that doesn't use ndb? My project isn't really revolved around it, so I'd need to make quite a few changes.